# Can not set the value in the label using delegate protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHDbH.png)i am making a program with delegate protocol in which we add value in text field in second controller and click save and this value is set to the label in the previous viewController
all the this are done but the value can not set to the label 
Can someone please explain me what is triggering the messageData() method in the main ViewController?

```
import UIKit

protocol SenderViewControllerDelegate {
    func messageData(data: String)
}

class NewViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK:- Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var firstTextField: UITextField!


    var delegate: SenderViewControllerDelegate?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




    @IBAction func SaveFirstValue(_ sender: Any) {
        if delegate != nil{
            if firstTextField.text != nil{
                let data = firstTextField.text
                delegate?.messageData(data: data!)
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,SenderViewControllerDelegate {

    //MARK:- Properties

    @IBOutlet var firstLabel: UILabel!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK:- Actions
    func messageData(data: String) {
        firstLabel.text = data
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showSendingVc" {
             let viewController : ViewController = segue.destination as! NewViewController

            ViewController.delegate = self
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: `ViewController.delegate = self` should be `viewController.delegate = self`

Comment: viewController.delegate = self, in your code viewController V is capital change it to small.   Add this let viewController = segue.destination as! NewViewController
    viewController.delegate = self

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
let viewController = segue.destination as! NewViewController
    viewController.delegate = self
```

Comment: i have update the code now there was no error but still not set value to the label

Comment: Check your IBOutlet to lable connected or not

Comment: it is connected to ViewController

Comment: What is your page redirection hierarchy, what is your main view controller

Answer (score 0):

You made mistake in the line `ViewController.delegate = self` it should be

```
viewController.delegate = self
```

means small **"v"** *(object of `ViewController`)*

**UPDATED:**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showSendingVc" {
             let objectOfVC = segue.destination as! NewViewController
            objectOfVC.delegate = self
        }
    }
```

Comment: getting this error in this line "cannot convert value of type uiviewcontroller to specified type"

Comment: i have update the code now there was no error but still not set value to the label

Answer (score 0):

```
   `ViewController.delegate = self` should be `viewController.delegate = self`

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showSendingVc" {
                 let viewController : NewViewController = segue.destination as! NewViewController //destination is type NewViewController not ViewController

               // ViewController.delegate = self //Wrong 
                viewController.delegate = self 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `ViewController` Class set the delegate inside `ViewDidLoad` method like this:

```
newViewControllerObj. delegate = self
```

Without calling `viewController` Class, the delegate will not set So you have to call `ViewController` class inside `NewViewController` or other class which will call first like that:

```
let ViewControllerObj = ViewController()
```